# How to abstract typical memory behavior from a complex multi-threaded workload?

Tags: performance, optimization, memory, profiling, intel

There is a complex multi-threaded program running in my system, which performs various types of operations. At the same time, I cannot access its source code.

I want to analyze the potential impact of its memory access behavior on performance for further optimization.

Is there a way to identify some typical memory access behavior and their proportion? For example, continuous memory reading and writing, linked list traversal, data sharing between threads, etc.

**[Intel's pin tool](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/developer/articles/tool/pin-a-dynamic-binary-instrumentation-tool.html) can generate load/store trace, can it be used for the above analysis? If possible, what should be done?**

**Are there other tools or methodologies that I can refer to?**

Comment: If you're looking for "bad" patterns like linked-list or tree traversal, you'd be looking for loads whose address depends on another recent load (not including loads from locals on the stack, like `[rsp+const]` addressing modes, unless store/reload is part of a chain).  IDK if PIN can help detect such patterns.

Comment: Other than that, the main things I'd look for would be loads that tend to miss in cache, especially ones that end up stalling execution.  e.g. on Intel (such as Skylake), there's an event `cycle_activity.stalls_l3_miss` which might be one to look for: *Execution stalls while L3 cache miss demand load is outstanding*.  An "execution stall" is when no uops are dispatched from the scheduler to an execution unit that cycle.  There are lots of other events for cache misses in various levels, and lines in/out.